# reinterpret_cast of a reference to a shared_ptr

Tags: c++, shared-ptr, reinterpret-cast

Let B be derived from class A. By reading various posts I've got an impression that casting like in

```
    const std::shared_ptr<const A> a(new B());
    const std::shared_ptr<const B>& b = reinterpret_cast<const std::shared_ptr<const B>&>(a);
```

is for some reason discouraged and that one should use reinterpret_pointer_cast instead. However, I would like to avoid creating a new shared_ptr for performance reasons. Is the above code legal? Does it lead to undefined behavior? It seems to work in gcc and in Visual Studio.

Comment: It's 100% undefined.

Comment: Why do you want to do this? Isn't the whole point of polymorphism to not know what the dynamic type is?

Comment: @curiousguy Is this strictly UB already? The cast is unspecified behavior, and I think it gets UB when you use the pointer because it violates the strict alias rule. Not that this kind of nitpicking really matters, but I am curious.

Comment: @Jens No it's UB because there is nothing to define the result of using a casted std class.

Comment: @curiousguy Can you explain what you mean by "nothing to define the result of using a casted std class"?

Comment: @Jens Doing, as in this Q, a cast then using dereferenced value to call functions (here members) is, well, not defined, anywhere. Can you quote a chapter where it is defined? No, so it's undefined.

Comment: @Jens "_because it violates the strict alias rule._" I intuitively don't think so. But I don't want to have to debate the most often debated rule in C and C++, the most confused one, the most problematic one, etc. when I just can avoid that.

Comment: @curiousguy Just casting is not UB: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58329972/does-casting-to-an-unrelated-reference-type-violate-the-strict-aliasing-rule/58330066#58330066. There is also a reference to the definition of what accessing an object means. I don't think that definition is satifying from a formal point of view.

Answer (score 1):

You want [static_pointer_cast](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/memory/static_pointer_cast/).

```
const std::shared_ptr<const A> a(new B());
const std::shared_ptr<const B> b = std::static_pointer_cast<const B>(a);
```

I highly doubt the above will cause any performance issues. But if you have evidence that a shared_ptr creates a performance problem, then fallback to the raw pointer:

```
    const B* pB = static_cast<const B*>(a.get());
```

Another hint.  Please try to avoid `reinterpret_cast` between classes with an inheritance relationship. In cases where there are virtual methods and/or multiple inheritance, the `static_cast` will correctly adjust the pointer offset to the correct vtable or base offset. But `reinterpret_cast` will not.  (Or technically: **undefined behavior**)

Comment: There is no inheritance relationship between shared_ptr<A> and shared_ptr<B>, so static_cast cannot be used. These classes should differ only in the type of the pointer that they are holding, and if this is really so than reinterpret_cast should be OK. I have an in-house version of shared_ptr and it's been working for years with reinterpret_cast. Now I want to switch to the standard shared_ptr. But you're right: I performed a test and your version with static_pointer_cast works as fast as mine. Thanks!

Comment: @DraganVidovic That sounds more like a recepie for disaster, even if it has been working for years. The only thing that is guaranteed with the result of your reinterpret_cast is that it can be converted back into the original type. What problem are you solving with the reinterpret_cast? If the classes are unrelated, I cannot see many reasons why I would like to treat two object identically.

Comment: @DraganVidovic If A and B are unrelated, how do you initialize `const std::shared_ptr<const A> a(new B());`? This failes because the pointer types are not assignable: https://wandbox.org/permlink/CgowZQBX54kf9vbc

Comment: @Jens: As stated in the question, "Let B be derived from class A." They are related; it is `shared_ptr<A>` and `shared_ptr<B>` that are unrelated.

Comment: @NicolBolas Thanks for pointing that out. I misread the comment.

Answer (score 0):

`reinterpret_cast` will usually lead to UB. Sometimes you are willing to take the risk of using it, for performances reasons, but you will try to avoid this kind of thing as much as you can. In this case, it better for you to use `static_pointer_cast`.

Pay attention, that even if you don't know, in this case, which other cast can you use, and you willing to take the risk with `reinterpret_cast`, you must use some validations after and before the casting- otherwise you will be able to get a lot of errors, and a lot of time spending.

Answer (score 0):

First, you create an object `a` of type `const std::shared_ptr<const A> a` and initialize it with a pointer to some type `B`. This only works if you can assign a `B*` to an `A*`, so there should be a relationship such as inheritance. Ignoring this, you convert an object of some type to a reference to another type with reinterpret_cast:

> A glvalue expression of type T1 can be cast to the type “reference to
>   T2” if an expression of type “pointer to T1” can be explicitly
>   converted to the type “pointer to T2” using a reinterpret_cast
>   The result refers to the same object as the source glvalue, but with
>   the specified type. [ Note: That is, for lvalues, a reference cast
>   reinterpret_cast(x) has the same effect as the conversion
>   *reinterpret_cast(&x) with the built-in & and * operators (and similarly for reinterpret_cast(x)). —end note ]

For pointers, reinterpret_cast boils down to conversion to `void*` and then to the target type:

> An object pointer can be explicitly converted to an object pointer of
>   a different type.72 When a prvalue v of object pointer type is
>   converted to the object pointer type “pointer to cv T”, the result is
>   `static_cast<cv T*>(static_cast<cv void*>(v))`.

The semantics of the two static casts are defined as:

> A prvalue of type “pointer to cv1 void” can be converted to a prvalue
>   of type “pointer to cv2 T,” where T is an object type and cv2 is the
>   same cv-qualification as, or greater cv-qualification than, cv1. The
>   null pointer value is converted to the null pointer value of the
>   destination type. If the original pointer value represents the address
>   A of a byte in memory and A satisfies the alignment requirement of T,
>   then the resulting pointer value represents the same address as the
>   original pointer value, that is, A. The result of any other such
>   pointer conversion is unspecified.

The platform I am working on has near and far pointers which are 16 or 32 bit. In that case, the types `shared_ptr<A>` and `shared_ptr<B>` are of different size and alignment, and casting one into the other is then unspecified behavior. If alignment matches, the result of the static casts is defined.

However, the first clause about reinterpret_cast to a reference also contains a note

> ```
> [ Note: That is, for lvalues, a reference
> cast reinterpret_cast<T&>(x) has the same effect as the conversion *reinterpret_cast<T*>(&x) with
> the built-in & and * operators (and similarly for reinterpret_cast<T&&>(x)). —end note ]
> ```

so basically, the cast is semantically identical to a pointer conversion with immediate dereferencing. Even if the pointers are of identical size (and compatible alignment), using the casted pointer will violate the strict alias rule since dereferencing is an access.

> If a program attempts to access the stored value of an object
>   through a glvalue of other than one of the
>       following types the behavior is undefined:53
>       — the dynamic type of the object,
>       — a cv-qualified version of the dynamic type of the object,
>       — a type similar (as defined in 4.4) to the dynamic type of the object,
>       — a type that is the signed or unsigned type corresponding to the dynamic type of the object,
>       — a type that is the signed or unsigned type corresponding to a cv-qualified version of the dynamic type
>       of the object,
>       — an aggregate or union type that includes one of the aforementioned types among its elements or nonstatic
>       data members (including, recursively, an element or non-static data member of a subaggregate
>       or contained union),

Comment: What is the "dynamic type of the object"?

Comment: @curiousguy The static type is the type of an expression inferred at compile time, e.g. the declared type of variable. The dynamic type is the type of the actual object, i.e. a pointer of type `A* a = new B()` points to an object with static type `A`, but with dynamic type `B`.

Comment: The actual object, as opposed to what, the *imaginary* object? What does `a` really points to? How can a `B` object have static type `A`?

Comment: @curiousguy Not sure what you are asking and where you imagine objects. Static and dynamic type are standard terms which can easily be googled. I try it again. Let's assume you have a `class A {public: virtual void foo() {} }` and a `class B: public A {}`. No imagine a function `void bar(A* a) {a->foo();}`. At compile time, you only now that whatever `a` points to is of type A. However, you can call `bar(new B())` and the actual type of the object that `a` points to is `B`, and the implementation in B will be called. This is the dynamic type, the type of the referenced object at runtime.

Comment: @curiousguy I did not imagine any objects, not sure where this is in my comment. I have a feeling you are making fun, so please be more specific where a static type is nonsense (maybe in a new question?). Could you elaborate your question concerning the pointer to a base? The pointer `a` of type `A*` points to an object at the given address, and this object is of type `B`. That is the whole point. The oibject looks like being of type `A`, i.e. you can only use `A`'s interface. This is the static type. But it actually is of type `B`, so the dynamic type is `B` and methods are resolved to `B`.

Comment: @curiousguy Or qutoing the C++ standard: "static type type of an expression  resulting from analysis of the program without considering execution semantics", whereas "<glvalue> type of the most derived object (1.8) to which the glvalue denoted by a glvalue expression refers [ Example: if a pointer (8.3.1) p whose static type is “pointer to class B” is pointing to an object of class D, derived from B (Clause 10), the dynamic type of the expression *p is “D.” References (8.3.2) are treated similarly."

Comment: No fun. Just rigor, as expected when dealing w/ PL semantics (but not often found in C++). "_this object is of type B._" of static or dynamic type `B`? What is meant by object of static type `A`? The type of the base class? The type of the expression?

Comment: Debate B: "_since dereferencing is an access_" Is it? Where is that defined? Is `int i; (void)(*(float*)&i);` an access of `i` as a `float`?

Comment: @curiousguy From the C++ standard: "The term object type refers to the type with which the object is created".

Comment: That's circular. The base is created as a base but then it's created to have a derived object. So which one is it: base or derived? The whole thing seems to be the completely random thoughts of committee members assembled in an incoherent mess.

Comment: It's not circular. Consider the program `A* a = new B(); *a`. There is one object created with `new B()` of type `B`. That should be something we can agree on. Then, there is another object `a` with type `A*`. Then when there is an expression `*a`, this expression has static type `A` (and `a` in this context has static type `A*`), derived from static analysis. But in our program we assigned the address of the object that was created with `new B()` to `a`, so it has dynamic type `B`. It is not an incoherent mess but really standard terminology for programming languages.

Answer (score 0):

Using functionalities of a `shared_ptr`, or any other standard class or template, is only defined when calling the functions (including member functions) for the class of the type which you pass to the function (including as implicit `this` argument):

*Nothing in the standard* defines what happens when you call a standard function expecting a `Foo` and passing a `Bar`, for any two standard types `Foo` and `Bar` (or even for user types.)

That's *not* defined; that's *un*defined. By not meeting the most basic precondition: to use arguments of the correct type.