# C++ strict aliasing and UB

Tags: c++, undefined-behavior, strict-aliasing, type-punning

I'm reviewing some code (can't post all of it), but there's a function like this:

```cpp
template <typename DestType, typename SourceType>
inline void transferDataAndUpdateSpan(MyArray<DestType>& to, MySpan<const SourceType>& source)
{
    static_assert(sizeof(DestType) == sizeof(SourceType), "Data size mismatch!!");
    to.resize(source.size());
    memcpy(to.data(), source.data(), sizeof(SourceType) * source.size());
    source = { (SourceType*)to.data(), to.size() };
}
```

`MySpan` is basically a typedef for `std::span` and `MyArray` is a container which has a constructor which receives a pointer to the data and the data size.

Question: isn't `source = { (SourceType*)to.data(), to.size() };` breaking strict aliasing here?
Is this triggering UB?

Comment: Isn't the question more suitable to https://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: @273K: No, this is a question about a suspected bug, codereview.se is only for code believed to be fully working.  The scope of codereview.se is not the same as the scope of software development process "code review" or "software inspection".

Comment: @Dean: There's a strict aliasing violation lurking here, but arguably it's not in this code, but it whatever tries to use `to` next.  Since its memory has been reused to store `SourceType`, it's illegal to keep accessing the `MyArray<DestType>` object.

Comment: Thanks but why isn't it a strict aliasing rule violation in that line? Doesn't it access data of a different object type with another object type? Just trying to understand here

Comment: That line **does not** access data of a different object type with another object type.  But it sets up the caller to do just that naughty thing.

Comment: Anti-aliasing is a graphics rendering trick, unrelated to strict aliasing. :)

Comment: The [C++ Standard - 7.2.1(11) \[expr.prop/basic.lval\]](https://eel.is/c++draft/expr#basic.lval-11) provides a bit more wiggle room than its C counterpart. The `memcpy()` has relevance on the issue from the C standard, though I find no similar language in the C++ standard. Others will have to chime in on the effect of `memcpy()`, if any, regarding the C++ effect.

Comment: I asked a similar question a while ago: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58329972/does-casting-to-an-unrelated-reference-type-violate-the-strict-aliasing-rule. Casting does not constitute an access so strictly it is not UB. Access is defined as "read or modify the value of an object".

Comment: @HolyBlackCat: Anti-aliasing is a signal processing technique to prevent the Sampling Theorem / Nyquist Criterion from introducing non-linearities, on any sort of sampled data.  Graphics rendering is just one extremely narrow application of the general pattern.

Comment: @BenVoigt Google gave me a rough idea of what the "aliasing" is in general, and what the sampling theorem has to do with it, but I still don't understand what you mean by the signal being "non-linear", or what the Nyquist criterion has to do with it.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat: It's not the signal that's non-linear, but the sampling process.  It results in frequencies in the result that were not present in the input or not present in the physical signal being represented digitally.  The Nyquist criterion tells you what sample density you need to avoid aliasing.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, the `memcpy` itself has undefined behavior if `DestType` (and `SourceType`?) aren't trivially-copyable or if the object representations in the `SourceType` objects aren't valid object representations for values of `DestType`.

A safer way to transferring the object representations would be to assign the result of `std::bit_cast` from the source element to the target element in a loop. It would at least verify trivial-copyability and would also include the size check you do manually at the moment.

Then, you say "*MyArray is a container which has a constructor which receives a pointer to the data and the data size*": But the constructor isn't used anywhere. You are just copying object representations. So hopefully `to.data()` is actually a pointer into an array of `DestType` objects into which `memcpy` can copy the object representations.

Then, `(SourceType*)to.data()` is a C-style cast, which are discouraged for a reason, especially in generic code like this: Depending on the types `SourceType` and `DestType` this can have completely different meaning.

If `SourceType` is for example a base class of `DestType`, then the cast will be a `static_cast` and the result will be a pointer to the `SourceType` base class subobject. This does in general change the address of the pointer and may fail to compile if the base class is inaccessible in the context (i.e. a `private` base class). Accessing the resulting pointer is generally fine, however doing pointer arithmetic on it (as your span probably is) would be UB, because the array into which the pointer points is an array of `DestType` objects, not `SourceType` objects. It is UB to do pointer arithmetic with a base class type into a derived class array.

If `SourceType` is a *derived* class of `DestType`, then the cast itself will still be a `static_cast`, but will have undefined behavior, because it would try to downcast a `DestType` object to its derived `SourceType` object which doesn't exist. An exception to this applies if implicit object creation applies as detailed below.

If there is no such base class relation, then the cast will end up as a `reinterpret_cast`, which does generally *not* change the address.

Generally, a `reinterpret_cast` also doesn't change to which object the pointer points, e.g. with `SourceType = float` and `DestType = int`, `(SourceType*)to.data()` will point to a `DestType` object, not a `SourceType` object. In such a situation the aliasing rule as well as rules for e.g. member access expressions apply and will make almost any use of the resulting pointer UB with very few exceptions.

An exception where a `reinterpret_cast` *does* change the pointer value to point to a different object is if there is an object of the target type that is *pointer-interconvertible* with the original object. That applies for example to first non-static data members of standard-layout classes without base classes. In that case aliasing can't be an issue because the resulting pointer will point to the actual subobject matching the type of the pointer. However, pointer arithmetic will still be faced with the exact same UB problem as stated above for `static_cast`.

Furthermore a `reinterpret_cast` can result in an unspecified value (which then causes UB on access or use in most expressions) if the alignment of the address isn't sufficient for the `SourceType`, which can happen if e.g. `SourceType` has a stricter alignment requirement than `DestType`.

In either case however, the cast itself will not cause UB (with the mentioned exception).

---

Additional note: If `SourceType` is an implicit-lifetime type `memcpy` could implicitly create `SourceType` objects in the `to.data()` storage, ending the lifetime of the previous `DestType` objects (and potentially the whole `MyArray` object). In that case there would (assuming the alignment is not a problem as stated above) be no issue with the cast to `SourceType` (except for a missing `std::launder`). However accessing the `to` elements as `DestType` later, or potentially using `to` at all, would then cause UB for accessing out-of-lifetime objects (or cause UB when doing pointer arithmetic in the case that `DestType` is a base of `SourceType`). That's probably not the intended use case.

---

To simplify all of this: You can't have a memory region be used as `SourceType` and `DestType` at the same time if they are different in more than cv-qualifications, with very few exceptions and practically no exception if you also want to do pointer arithmetic on the memory region in both types at the same time.

---

All of the above is based strictly on what the standard says is or isn't UB. Practically speaking for example I do not expect any compiler to behave unexpected when doing pointer arithmetic in the wrong type as long as the types have the same size and alignment requirement. However violations of the aliasing rule *will* cause problems in practice.

Comment: In addition to cv-qualification adjustments, type punning between corresponding signed and unsigned integral types is also ok.  Great analysis overall.

Comment: @BenVoigt Yes, that's true for directly accessing the the first element through the pointer, plus some more aliasing exceptions as listed in [\[basic.lval\]/11](https://eel.is/c++draft/expr#basic.lval-11). However, for pointer arithmetic the types must be _similar_, i.e. may only differ in cv-qualifications (https://eel.is/c++draft/expr.add#6).